# read input file and post with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a portion of a form that is submitted by ajax to a PHP script
I can't submit the all form, I can't grab the all formData:

```
var formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
```

What I do is read the value of text input fields, and post them via ajax ( with jQuery ) and it works ok with test field.

After this sample code I catch the ajax result :

```
var field1 = $('#field1').val();
var field2 = $('#field2').val();

var postData = {
  'field1': field1,
  'field2': field2
};

var formInvio = $.ajax({
  url: 'ajax-post.php',
  type: 'POST',                 
  data: postData,
  dataType: 'json',
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  encode: true
});
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get an image input file and add it to postData

In the form I have a file field:

```
<input type="file" name="myimg" id="myimg">
```

but reading `val()` doesn't work:

```
var myimg = $('#myimg').val();
```

Comment: Google has enough results for that problem.

Comment: *...i don't know hot to get an image input file and add it to postData*. Google it dude.

Comment: Is one of those fields a `type="file"`? Also check into `new FormData`

Comment: all the results that i found tell to to read the all form like var formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0]); but i can't since i need to post only part of a bigger form

Comment: one of the fields is type="file"

Comment: @al404IT edit your post with more details then. FormData will still work, but you can't just grab the `value` of file input and hope it does what you want.

Comment: @al404IT This is also discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery